# How do I put the Yoxview infoPanel right under the Image

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, yoxview

In yoxview, I specified that the #yoxview_infoPanel should appear outside the image box by inserting the custom options in the $(document).ready statement:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){

                $(".yoxview").yoxview({

    renderInfoExternally:"true",

                });

            });

        </script>
```

However, now the info panel appear on the very bottom the page. How do I put the info panel below right below the image, centered?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you're running YoxView in ab jQuery version newer than 1.5.2? If you are, it does do unexpected things. Try going back to 1.4 or 1.5 and see if it responds correctly.

Comment: That was the answer. I say thanks to you in name of that user ^^

Comment: Hi Michael. I say thanks as well!!! :) We ended up using another option but you don't know when this will come handy again!

Answer (score 0):

From this post:

https://drupal.org/node/1677038

it seems that YoxView works with recent jQuery versions if you:

> do a find/replace on your jquery.yoxview-2.21.min.js file for "className" (make sure of the casing, capital N) and replace it with "class". When you do the find/replace for className, make sure you specify that it must match *exactly*, both the "full word" and "case sensitive". There are other variable names that include "className", and if you replace that part with "class" it may break it.